# How does the Shadow DOM effect component lifecycle methods in stenciljs

Tags: shadow-dom, stenciljs

I am trying to understand how using the Shadow DOM effects a components lifecycle methods in Stenciljs.

I have set up the following example in a Stencil starter app.

```
<body>
  <my-app>
    <component-a>
      <component-c />
    </component-a>
    <component-b />
    </my-app> 
    ...
</body>
```

Components are defined as:

```
@Component({
  tag: 'my-app',
  styleUrl: 'my-app.css'
})
@Component({
  tag: 'component-a'
})
@Component({
  tag: 'component-b'
})
@Component({
  tag: 'component-c'
})
```

Each component has console statements in each of its lifecycle methods. When the page loads in the browser without any of the components having the shadow DOM turned on.

```
09:30:00.603 my-app.js:19 my-app  is about to be rendered
09:30:00.605 component-a.js:19 component-a  is about to be rendered
09:30:00.606 component-c.js:19 component-c  is about to be rendered
09:30:00.606 component-c.js:30 component-c  has been rendered
09:30:00.607 component-a.js:30 component-a  has been rendered
09:30:00.607 component-b.js:19 component-b  is about to be rendered
09:30:00.608 component-b.js:30 component-b  has been rendered
09:30:00.608 my-app.js:30 my-app  has been rendered
```

Turning the Shadow DOM on in component-a alters the rendering.

```
@Component({
  tag: 'component-a',
  shadow: true
})
```

The Console output changes to :

```
09:33:22.840 my-app.js:19 my-app  is about to be rendered
09:33:22.842 component-a.js:19 component-a  is about to be rendered
09:33:22.843 component-b.js:19 component-b  is about to be rendered
09:33:22.843 component-b.js:30 component-b  has been rendered
09:33:22.844 component-c.js:19 component-c  is about to be rendered
09:33:22.845 component-c.js:30 component-c  has been rendered
09:33:22.845 component-a.js:30 component-a  has been rendered
09:33:22.845 my-app.js:30 my-app  has been rendered
```

component-b is now being rendered before both component-a and component-c are rendered. I am not sure how rendering the page with the Shadow DOM effects this change.

Answer (score 1):

In my tests the render order can be one of three different ones on every request. I don't see any change when enabling Shadow DOM on any of the components.

I used the same 3 components and refreshed the page several times. These are the three different outputs:

```
Component A is about to be rendered
Component B is about to be rendered
Component B has been rendered
Component C is about to be rendered
Component C has been rendered
Component A has been rendered

-- Hard Refresh --

Component A is about to be rendered
Component C is about to be rendered
Component C has been rendered
Component A has been rendered
Component B is about to be rendered
Component B has been rendered

-- Hard Refresh --

Component B is about to be rendered
Component B has been rendered
Component A is about to be rendered
Component C is about to be rendered
Component C has been rendered
Component A has been rendered
```

In practice it probably won't matter which in order they're rendered as long as they follow the [Lifecycle Hierarchy](https://stenciljs.com/docs/component-lifecycle/#lifecycle-hierarchy), which they do (at least for the `componentDidLoad` method).